# Why is the iOS emulator in VSCode among the options?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, simulator

[image]

I am using MacBook why I can't see iOS emulators a few days ago and I could use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in the Flutter Discord server help me:

"Could be that you settings in Xcode changed.  Go to preferences > locations > Command Line Tools and make sure it is set to your Xcode"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).